# One trigger effects another trigger code coverage in Test class

Tags: unit-test

Junction platform is linked to platform ,account and document access.

Trigger on junction platform in case of "insert".
**Junction platform Trigger Purpose**:
              if Junction platform doesn't contain any document access record. then that trigger on junction platform will create a new  document access record.

Trigger on account object. Account is parent to document access. **Account Trigger purpose**:If account is linked to junction platform, if  that junction platform doesnt contain child document access record ,trigger will  create new document access record.

But in test class,Creation of junction platform record,that time Junction platform trigger will run and it creates new document access record.But  At any cost documentacessmap.values not be null in account trigger.It gives  documentacessmap.values  is 1. How to resolve the issue?

So following line of code will not cover

[image]

Test class:

```
   @isTest
public class S360_AccountDocumentAccess_Test {
public static testmethod void testdetails(){
    Account ac=S360_TestDataFactory.createAccountRecords();
    Platform__c plat=S360_TestDataFactory.createPlatformRecords();
    Junction_Platform__c junction=S360_TestDataFactory.createJunctionPlatformLsit(ac.id,plat.id);
    ac.PIA_Status__c=false;
    update ac; }}
```

---

```
public class S360_AccountDocumentAccess {
public static void documentDetails(List<Account> accountList){
    List<Document_Access__c> docList=new List<Document_Access__c>();
    set<id> Accountset=new set<id>();
    set<id> Accountid=new set<id>();
    map<id,Integer> documentacessmap=new map<id,Integer>();
    map<id,id> platformmap=new map<id,id>();
    map<id,id> Junctionmap=new map<id,id>();
    set<id> junctionId=new set<id>();
    map<id,id> accountmap=new map<id,id>();
    set<id>Junctionset=new set<id>();

    for(Account ac:accountList){
        Accountset.add(ac.Id);
    }
    list<Junction_Platform__c> junctionPlat=[select id,Account__c,Platform__c from Junction_Platform__c where Account__c in:Accountset];

    for(Junction_Platform__c junc:junctionPlat){
        junctionId.add(junc.id);
    }

      for(Junction_Platform__c junc:[select id,Account__c,Platform__c,(select id,Processing__c from Document_Access__r where Processing__c=false) from Junction_Platform__c where id in:junctionId]){
        documentacessmap.put(junc.id,junc.Document_Access__r.size());
        accountmap.put(junc.Id,junc.Account__c);
        junctionmap.put(junc.Id,junc.Platform__c);
    }
    system.debug('document access map values###'+documentacessmap.values());

      for(Junction_Platform__c ju:junctionPlat){

        if(documentacessmap.get(ju.id)==0){  
            Junctionset.add(ju.id);
        }
    }


   if(!Junctionset.isEmpty()){
        for(Junction_Platform__c pl:junctionPlat){
            Document_Access__c  doc=new Document_Access__c();
            doc.Account__c=accountmap.get(pl.id); 
            doc.Platform__c=junctionmap.get(pl.id);
            doc.Processing__c=false;
            doc.Operation__c='Update';
            doc.Junction_Platform__c=pl.id;
            doc.Updated_via__c='Account';
            docList.add(doc);
        }

    }
    system.debug('@@docList@@@'+docList);
    if(!docList.isEmpty()){
        insert docList;
    }  
}}
```

Comment: Why not just do `if(!documentacessmap.containsKey(ju.id)){}`  Your code has a lot of null pointer failure points, You need to put in more debugs here to see why you're failing to get into your `if` statements

Comment: In your condition map says that Junction id is not present. In my case Junction id will be present but its child records size will be zero.

Comment: i don't know why people down voted it without understanding the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also don't see why this has been down-voted. Perhaps the mere mention of "code coverage" gets people to vote down. Seems like a fair question to me.

Can't you delete the Document Access objects in the middle of your test? Something like this:

```
@IsTest
public class S360_AccountDocumentAccess_Test {

    @IsTest
    public static testmethod void testdetails(){
        Account ac=S360_TestDataFactory.createAccountRecords();
        delete [SELECT Id FROM Document_Access__c];
        Platform__c plat=S360_TestDataFactory.createPlatformRecords();
        Junction_Platform__c junction=S360_TestDataFactory.createJunctionPlatformLsit(ac.id,plat.id);
        ac.PIA_Status__c=false;
        update ac; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Ya.It works for me. Any other alternative ways?

Comment: This isn't necessarily a bad way to do it. You haven't included the trigger on Account that creates a Document_Access__c. If you can choose to create your test Account in a way that doesn't cause the Account trigger to create a Document_Access__c, then that would be better. The method in my answer is legitimate for some use-cases though e.g. when you have legacy Account records in the system that have not been through your Account trigger. Your test needs to create something that looks like one of these legacy Accounts - deleting the Document_Access__c does that for you